# Software cannot connect SQL remotely from VS, but can outside of it

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I'm writing WPF applications using VS 2010, defining the DataContext to take connection string from setting files, and also drag tables from DB into .dbml file.
For a long time everything worked Ok, then suddenly the I've got a problem:
"a network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to sql server"
The wierd thing is that when I'm making a version out of it - it works OK!!!!!!!!
(The settings file has no changed in many weeks, but it worked ok until several days ago...)
Any help will be appreciated....
Thanks,
Rivka

Comment: In VS and out you are running as the same logon?

Comment: Yes, of course, I'm making a version, install it in my computer, and it runs without problems....

Answer (score 0):

Wow... I've got it:
The difference between the project on vs and the installed version was - the volume it was located on. The vs was located on one of the network servers and it seems that the deifinion access were changed several days ago....(the installed version was on local disk....)
I've moved the project to another volume - and it worked...